# NullPointerException on spoj/ideone

Tags: java, string, split, nullpointerexception

I'd created a program to my homework, i tried it to test on ideone.com, but i get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Main.main(Main.java:83)
```

for every test(in elipse workin' fine)

line 83:

```
 String[] val = tab.split(" ");
```

line 82: // only for informational purpose

```
String tab = in.readLine();
```

line 78:// only for informational purpose

```
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

Comment: Can you add the complete code?
Try debugging by printing ( System.out.print ) every object before it is used. tab, in, val. tab is being null, but it could be chain effect. it could also be that the in.readLine is returning null somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scanner is greedily pulling in the full input on the first call to `nextInt`. I recommend using either the scanner or the buffered reader--but not both. Having them both reading from the same stream is causing problems.

Remove the scanner and change the way you grab the first number:

```
String count = in.readLine();
int i = Integer.valueOf(count);
```

Comment: Thanks, now works fine :) I've didn't realize It could do problem like this, I had in few programs 2 inputs on System.in and works ok on ideone

Comment: In the [source for `Scanner`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Scanner.java) you can see that it uses an internal `java.nio.CharBuffer` to read from the source input stream in chunks to improve performance, much like `BufferedReader`.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly it is due to the fact that you try to read single stream with two different readers. Try to use Integer.valueOf(in.readLine()) instead of creating scanner and calling sc.nextInt() or use only scanner.